# Spivak Calculus 20-9

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

This question is from Spivak's Calculus (3rd) Problem 20-9:

[image]

I'm having problem with part (c).  It seems that $g$ is arbitrary so I'm not sure how the earlier parts help.

Comment: The earlier part is just for you to have the intuition of what is going to happen. Apply chain rule.

Comment: If you apply chain rule and differentiate once then do you get $f'(x)=g'(x^n)nx^(n-1)$?  I don't know doesn't seem right.

Comment: That is the first derivative. You have to compute the kth and evaluate in zero

Comment: @JoaquinSan  If we keep applying it and evaluate at 0 then don't we always get 0, until k>n?

Comment: Ok. Now what happened in b)?